# Oracle query to find start and end dates of active status records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like following

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+
| Code | StartDate | EndDate  | Unit  | CodeStatus |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+
| 1001 |  20100101 | 20101231 | UnitA | Active     |
| 1001 |  20110101 | 20151231 | UnitB | Active     |
| 1001 |  20160101 | 21000101 | UnitB | Inactive   |
| 1002 |  20160101 | 20181231 | UnitA | Active     |
| 1002 |  20190101 | 21000101 | UnitA | Inactive   |
| 1003 |  20140101 | 21000101 | UnitC | Active     |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------------+
```

If we look at first code(1001) there are two active records, in output I want least start date and highest end date of active records. Something like below

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Code | StartDate | EndDate  | Status   |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1001 | 20100101  | 20151231 | Inactive |
| 1002 | 20181231  | 20181231 | Inactive |
| 1003 | 20140101  | 21000101 | Active   |
+------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

This table has around million records and I pull data using api, so performance also a matter.

Can someone please help me with query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need just max and min aggregate function

```
   with cte as
  (
   select code,min(StartDate) as mStartDate,
   max(EndDate)  as mEndDate from table
   where CodeStatus='Active' group by code
  ) 
  ,cte1 as
  (
   select CodeStatus,code,
   row_number()over(partition by code order by StartDate desc) rn
   from table
 ) select cte.*,cte1.CodeStatus 
   from cte join cte1 on cte.code=cte1.code
   where cte1.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed one point in my description, I need to add current status to those codes, for example for 1001-Inactive, 1003-Active etc.

Comment: @GreenStar what is the logic of getting current status

Comment: I need to display the most recent status.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the period when the code is active and the current status.  This is a basic aggregation query with a twist:

```
select code,
       min(case when codestatus = 'Active' then start_date end) as active_start_date,
       max(case when codestatus = 'Active' then end_date end) as active_end_date,
       max(codestatus) keep (dense_rank first order by start_date desc) as current_code_status
from codes
group by code;
```

`keep` is a nice feature in Oracle that is essentially an aggregate `first_value()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result you posted from the sample data you posted, you could use conditional aggregation. I.e. only pass the dates to `min()` or `max()` if the status is active. Like that you get your minimum and maximum. To get the current status check if the current time is after or at the start time and before the end time. If it is pass the status to e.g. `max()`.

```
SELECT code,
       to_char(min(CASE
                    WHEN codestatus = 'Active' THEN
                      startdate
                   END), 'YYYYMMDD') startdate,
       to_char(min(CASE
                    WHEN codestatus = 'Active' THEN
                      enddate
                   END), 'YYYYMMDD') enddate,
       max(CASE
             WHEN startdate <= sysdate
                  AND enddate > sysdate THEN
               codestatus
           END) status
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY code
       ORDER BY code;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1cde284ac176e963ed4793ea0f8bd9f1)

But I suspect there may be more to it. What if there are more active periods than one? Is it correct to take the start of the earliest and the end of the latest? What if there's more periods matching current time, which one determines the current status?

Comment: Thank you. Once code is inactive, it will not be active again. But codes unit may change time to time during active period. These is one code in of DB that changed 14 times before it turned into Inactive. I will try this solution and see how it goes. I am not a DB guy so the query could be simple for many but I tried my best. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to get the start and end dates as well as the current status for your codes.  Performance will be determined by what you limit the selection in the WITH section to either by code or by date.

```
 WITH CodeDates AS 
 (
   select 
       code,
       min(StartDate)  startdate,
       max(EndDate)    enddate
     from table
    Group by code
 )
  Select c.code,
         c.startdate
         c.enddate,
         t.codestatus
   From CodeDates c
   Join table  t
     on t.code = c.code
     and t.enddate = c.enddate
```